# insertAdjacentHTML then select with dom selector

Tags: javascript, insertadjacenthtml

I want to insert some unknown HTML (contentToInsert) and remove it later at some point.

If I use insertAdjacentHTML, I cannot later say

```
 myDiv.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', contentToInsert);
 myDiv.querySelector('contentToInsert') //cannot work of course
```

because this does not have id or classname.

I cannot wrap it like this (so I have reference to it later):

```
var content = document.createElement('div');
content.classList.add('my-content-wrap')
content.innerHTML = contentToInsert;

myDiv.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', adContent);//it can be any allowed position, not just afterbegin
```

Basically I want to remove it later at some point but dont know how to select it. I dont know the position in which this is going to be instered.

Comment: [please show HTML / JS sample code...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Why can't you wrap it? You can insert `content` using `insertAdjacentElement()`

Comment: What are you inserting, plain text or HTML? If you are inserting HTML content, you can give an id to that HTML and later fetch the content using this id.

Comment: `let content = document.createElement('div');
content.classList.add('my-content-wrap');
content.innerHTML = contentToInsert; myDiv.prepend(content);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `insertAdjacentHTML` only accepts a string you can

1. Define your content as a string
2. Use a [template/string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to add it
3. Add that string to `myDiv`.

Then you can target `myDiv` again with a selector pointed at that element with the `my-content-wrap` class, and remove it from the DOM.

```js
const myDiv = document.querySelector('#myDiv');
const content = 'Disappears after two seconds';
const html = `<div class="my-content-wrap">${content}</div>`;

myDiv.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', html);

const pickup = myDiv.querySelector('.my-content-wrap');

setTimeout(() => pickup.remove(), 2000);
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">Original content</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You said "I want to insert some unknown HTML (contentToInsert) and remove it later at some point"

I wouldn't use insertAdjacentHTML at all. Here's how you can achieve it:

```
let myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');
let contentToInsert = "<h1>Some html content</h1>";

myDiv.innerHTML = contentToInsert;
```

This will insert your content into your div. And you can remove it with:

```
myDiv.innerHTML = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

in one of the cases...

```js
const 
  divElm   = document.querySelector('#div-elm')
, Insert_1 = '<span>inserted content 1 </span>'
, Insert_2 = '<span>inserted content 2 </span>'
  ;

divElm.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', Insert_1);
const ref_1 = divElm.firstChild;

divElm.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', Insert_2);
const ref_2 = divElm.firstChild;

ref_1.classList.add('RED')
ref_2.classList.add('BLU')

console.log( '', ref_1, `\n`, ref_2 )
```

```css
.RED { color: red; }
.BLU { color: blue; }
```

```html
<div id="div-elm">
  blah blah bla..
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

many amazing people already answered your question but here's a workaround, if you're only Adding this specific html using js and other content is preadded in html it's always gonna be the first child as you're using `afterbegin`  or else you can do it like others gave you examples.

Sorry can't comment not enough reputation and recently joined